July 2024 roadmap blog post contains http (not https) links
Tl;dr - Could this blog post be updated to use https:// links for MSO/MSE in the final paragraph? Consider using the site names (not domain names) in the visible text, too (meta.stackexchange.com → Meta Stack Exchange)

This blog post, titled Community Products Roadmap Update, July 2024, contains plain http:// links to MSE and MSO at the end:

As always, we’re excited to share learnings as we go and value your input along the way. If you’d like to provide your input, we invite you to join the conversation on meta.stackexchange.com, meta.stackoverflow.com, or opt into our user research list.

While all the other links appear to be https://, can someone edit the blog to use HTTPS links to MSE & MSO?
I'd also suggest using the site names rather than the domain names. Something like this, maybe...

... join the conversation on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow, or opt into our user research list.


Got as feeling this is a dupe, or was that the previous blog......

@W.O. Not sure. Looking at this previous one, it has the same issue, although this was for the current one (released 2024 July 1), so I don't think there's a dupe for the current one, although it's entirely possible there's a dupe for the last one.

Oh, yes, it's a recurrent issue. Figures that's because it's done manually. Machine checking would have prevented that, but I guess that's not a priority.
